# how to fix "customers" shows object Object

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to fix "customers" shows object Object
I tried to load the ajax content but it shows [object Object]. Can anyone help?

```js
 $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
            //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
            var customers = new Array();
            $("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var customer = {};
                customer.Name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                customer.Country = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                customers.push(customer);
            });
             console.log(customers);

            //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/InsertCustomers",
                data: JSON.stringify(customers),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing `[object Object]`, it means `r` is an object. That's what you get when you convert an object that has the default `toString` to a string (for instance, by combining it with a string via `+`).

You'll need to look at what the object is in order to find out what property(ies) you want to display from it. You can do that using the debugger built into your browser (set a breakpoint on your current `alert` line) or the Network tab of your browser (look at the ajax response content, which is apparently JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code. Your receiving object, so check your console screen.

```
var name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
var country = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/InsertCustomers",
                data: {Name : name,Country : country},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    console.log(r);
                }
            });
```